# Missing assets provided by .aar library in application built using Android.bp

Tags: android, android-source, aar, lib

I have a third-party aar library which contains several files (like .so and assets).

The aar file has his own Android.bp file like:

```
android_library_import{
   aars: [myaar.aar],
   name: "myaar"
}
```

My application includes it as follows:

```
android_app{
   ...
   static_libs: [
      "myaar"
   ]
}
```

It builds correctly but there is a runtime crash due to the missing assets.. if I compare the APK generated in AOSP using my .bp and the equivalent generated in Android Studio all the assets provided by the .aar are missing. How should I tell the build system to pack also those?
If I go under out/ and go in the intermediates of the .aar I see all the contents so they are correctly picked up by the build system but they are not included in the APK

Thanks to anyone can give a feedback!